# Jquery retrieve values of Dynamically created elements

Tags: forms, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a html page with a form.
The form has Div which gets populated dynamically with Input elements like text box,radio,checkbox etc.

Now I want to ***retrieve the values of these dynamically created elements*** in the Html page,so that i can submit it to a page.

**//HTML PAGE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {
            populateQuestions();
         });    

         $("#submit_btn").click(function() {
             // validate and process form here
            //HOW TO ??retrieve values???
             var optionSelected = $("input#OptionSelected_1").val();// doesn't work?

            // alert(optionSelected); 
             postAnswer(qid,values);//submit values 
             showNextQuestion() ;// populate Div Questions again new values
         });  


     </script>

    <form action="" name="frmQuestion">
    <div id="Questions" style="color: #FF0000">

    </div>
```

**//Question DIV generation script** example radio buttons

```
//questionText text of question
//option for question questionOptions
// **sample call**
 var question = createQuestionElement("1","MCQ", "WHAT IS ABCD??", "Opt1$Opt2$Opt3");
 question.appendTo($('#Questions'));


function createQuestionElement(id, type, questionText, questionOptions) {
    var questionDiv = $('<div>').attr('id', 'Question');
    var divTitle = $('<div>').attr('id', 'Question Title').html(questionText);
    divTitle.appendTo(questionDiv);    
    var divOptions = $('<div>').attr('id', 'Question Options');     
    createOptions(id, "radio", questionOptions, divOptions);
    divOptions.appendTo(questionDiv);
    return questionDiv;
}

function createOptions(id, type, options, div) {
    var optionArray = options.split("$");
    // Loop over each value in the array.
    $.each(
 optionArray, function(intIndex, objValue) {
     if (intIndex == 0) {
         div.append($("<input type='" + type + "' name='OptionSelected_" + id + "' checked='checked'  value='" + objValue + "'>"));
     } else {
         div.append($("<input type='" + type + "' name='OptionSelected_" + id + "' value='" + objValue + "'>"));
     }
     div.append(objValue);
     div.append("<br/>");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the same input multiple times, since you're splitting the option array, you're making this:

```
<input type='radio' name='OptionSelected_1' checked='checked'  value='Opt1'>
<input type='radio' name='OptionSelected_1' value='Opt2'>
<input type='radio' name='OptionSelected_1' value='Opt3'>
```

You are currently fetching by ID with the `#`, instead you want to fetch by `name` and get the `:checked` item, like this:

```
var optionSelected = $("input[name=OptionSelected_1]:checked").val();
```

Comment: Amitd - I re-read the code...try the updated answer, should do what you're after, please comment if it doesn't

Comment: yep done now ..was testing the code..
can had a question if thr are multiple radio button groups or questions..how to select those values?how to count number of input elements within the form??

Comment: @Amitd - A count of total elements would be: `$("input").length"` or `$(":input").length` if you wanted all input types (textarea, button, etc) or just `$(":radio")` for all radio elements only.  To get other values, you can loop through, etc..depends what you want to do with them.  For example this would loop through showing the checked values that have a name stating with `OptionSelected_`: `$("input[name^=OptionSelected_]:checked").each(function() { alert($(this).val(); });`