# dynamically retrieve textbox values using foreach jquery which itself is dynamically created

Tags: jquery, html, input, modal-dialog, modalpopups

How to dynamically retrieve values from input text box :

```
   $(":input").each(function(){alert($(this).text());});
```

Case :

Dynamically column names are taken from xml source & binded in this manner :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "GetColumnNames.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    var cWidth =  100/(xml.getElementsByTagName("Column")).length;
                    $(xml).find('Column').each(function(){
                        var cId = $(this).find('Id').text();
                        var cName = $(this).find('Name').text();
                        $('<td id='+cId+' width='+cWidth+'>'+cName+'</td>').appendTo('#page-wrap');
                        $('<label for='+cName+'>'+cName+'<input type="text" name='+cName+'id='+cName+' value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></label>').appendTo('#moreItems');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The `#moreItems` is part of another div which is part of modal popup and i want to access values within that,

So,

after validation i go this way :

```
   if ( bValid ) {


                       $(":text").each(function(){
                        alert($(this).text());
                       });

}
```

But still i am not able to access input values.

Note :

It is not similar to :

[How do I retrieve a textbox value using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320088/how-do-i-retrieve-a-textbox-value-using-jquery) ,
[Jquery retrieve values of Dynamically created elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461343/jquery-retrieve-values-of-dynamically-created-elements) ,
[how do i retrieve a textbox's title and name using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730607/how-do-i-retrieve-a-textboxs-title-and-name-using-jquery) ,

Looking for your help ..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `$` sign. It should be:

```
$(":text").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

You should also try to generate well-formed HTML, with attributes delimited by quote characters:

```
$('<td id="'+cId+'" width="'+cWidth+'">'+cName+'</td>').appendTo('#page-wrap');
$('<label for="'+cName+'">'+cName+'<input type="text" name="'+cName+'" id="'
    +cName+'" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></label>')
    .appendTo('#moreItems');
```

Comment: OMG! Thanks.. But now i am getting a blank alert.values within text are NOT reterived.Please guide

Comment: @Pratik, that probably comes from your generated markup. See my updated answer.

Comment: I guess  its the same. I tried formatted HTML as well but still stuck at same place.Not able to retrieve values from input text box

Comment: @Pratik, as a last resort, try using `val()` instead of `text()`. Also, all the values in your generated markup are empty, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: val() perfectly works But what went wrong Why text() didn't work. Any ideas. Thanks lot !

Comment: @Pratik, that would be because [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) returns the inner text of an element, not its value.